# How to use UITextInputMode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I need create a method which detects keyboard input language . for example when keyboard language is French does something and when is English does something else

I search on the Internet and found `UITextInputMode`  but I don't know how to use it , I would be grateful if you help me . thanks

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputMode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UITextInputMode/currentInputMode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite simple, you can do it this way:

```
UITextInputMode *textInput = [UITextInputMode currentInputMode];
NSString *primaryLanguage = textInput.primaryLanguage;
NSLog(@"Current text input is: %@", primaryLanguage);
```

As noted in Apple docs, *"The value of this property is a BCP 47 language code such as “es”, “en-US”, or “fr-CA”"*.

If you need to be notified about changes, you add your controller as observer for `UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification`

Comment: thanks , I put this code in viewDidLoad and the log message is 
`Current text input is: (null)` actually I have UISearchBar which needs to detect keyboard input in it

Comment: So you need to call this when you have some UITextField or search bar as the firstResponder ( = the keyboard on the screen). You can call it when you the delegate method `- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar`

Comment: what about Klingon ?

Comment: I see this warning. 'currentInputMode' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0

Comment: Also, it always returns en-US even if I change the keyboard language by choosing the globe icon